# C# Visual Studio issue, data is saved in table adapter but database doesn't get updated

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I am new to C#.

I have created:

1. Local Service-based database
2. DataSet for the table (users)
3. Table Adapter
4. SQL Insert queries inside the table adapter

My SQL query syntax is ok and run fine. Problem occurs when I use this bit of code:

```
adapter.Insert("values");
adapter.Update(DataSet);
```

The first line runs ok and I can login to that user account that is inserted. But nothing comes to the database. Also, when I close the app and open it again, I cannot login to that user anymore.

Changing the database copy to "Copy Always" / "Don't copy".

"Don't copy" caused this error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database.

I am currently using "Copy if newer"

I am not required to use any inline SQL command in my code, I have added the binding source, dataSet, table adapter from the toolBox to my form and configured the datasource of them accordingly.

Comment: Does this `I am not required to use any inline SQL command in my code` mean this is homework? Can you login using Server Explorer in Visual Studio?

Comment: How is your question related to visual studio 2022?

Comment: This is rare in the days of entity framework I guess. Takes me back some years. See here for an example: [SavingDataADO](https://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/SavingDataADO.html) and also here [dataset-tutorial](https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/ado-net/dataset-tutorial-with-c-ado-net-programming-example.php) Be sure to notice that we can us a OleDbCommandBuilder to "build" the CRUD (insert, update, delete) statements you need. You can see how this can be done manually here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters